# Is it possile to map people that have certain permissions in voice channel? Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm a discord bot developer writing in JS.
I'm currently trying to map users that have "CONNECT" permission on ina voice channel for some private donator channels, so donators can see who they have whitelisted.
Here's my code:

```js
if (!message.member.voiceChannel) {

            let novoice = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setDescription("Please join your voice chat to use this command.")
            .setColor(config.orange)

            message.delete()
            message.channel.send({ embed: novoice }).then(msg => msg.delete(10000));
            return

        } else if (message.member.voiceChannel.name.includes('')) {

            let list = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(` List of whitelisted members in ${message.member.voiceChannel}`)
            .setDescription(message.member.voiceChannel.members.filter(members => members.hasPermission('CONNECT') === true).join(" "))

            message.channel.send({ embed: list });
            return

        }
```

Please let me know if you have an idea or a tip ho to solve this problem.
Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by looping over the guild's members and adding any with permission to connect to the channel to your list.

```js
let whitelisted = [];
let members = message.guild.members.array();

for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
  if (message.member.voiceChannel.permissionsFor(members[i]).has('CONNECT')) whitelisted.push(`<@${members[i].id}>`);
}

let list = whitelisted.join(', '); // mentions of each user
```

---

**EDIT:**

*Looking back on my own answer, I honestly wouldn't upvote it. Here's the solution I wish I would have provided the first time.*

You can also use the [`Collection#filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) method which evaluates the function passed to it with each value. In this way it determines which to add to the new Collection based on the return value (truthy/falsy). Note that the original Collection is left unchanged—a new one is returned instead.

```js
// discord.js v11
const whitelisted = message.guild.members.filter(
  (m) => member.voiceChannel.permissionsFor(m).has('CONNECT')
);

// discord.js v12
const whitelisted = message.guild.members.cache.filter(
  (m) => member.voice.channel.permissionsFor(m).has('CONNECT')
);
```

```js
whitelisted.array().join(', '); // list of mentions
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was honestly out of ideas :P